# How to group by month+year?

Tags: php, mysql, grouping

http://www.bioshapebenefits.nl/bioshapebenefits/en/news/donations.html

As you see, here I have a long list of entries, sorted by date, very simple. So in mysql there would only be the columns 'name' and 'date', for example. And if I'd want to make a list out of it with php that would also be very simple, just sorting by date.

But how would I put the months+years in between, as shown in the example? Like:

June 2010

- Trala
- Lala
- Wala

May 2010

- Trala
- Lala
- Wala

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server it would be as simple as the following, I'd imagine mysql has something similar:

`GROUP BY Year(Date), Month(Date)`

Comment: Damn! Beat me by 42 seconds. To my knowledge this is correct.

Comment: @RedFilter, I tried to cover that in my answer - so far I've only looked into mySQL having come from a SQL Server / Oracle background.  But typically in every case I've looked at all three always seem very close on all core functionality.

Comment: Bear in mind though this will be very resource consuming, if you do these kind of queries often, consider adding fields just with months and years (compute them before inserting).

Comment: @Raveren:  Very good point - I forgot to add that one, I've had to denormalise" data on several times, adding those two columns (and indexing them) to maximise performance later on selects.

Answer (score 5):

There's a dozen ways to skin this cat, but my approach would probably be like this (all rough code snippets, not a full implementation)

First, the query

```
select `name`
     , month(`date`) as date_month
     , year(`date`) as date_year
  from [Table]
 order by `date` desc
```

Then, organize the data into the desired logical groups

```
$templateData = array();
foreach ( $rows as $row )
{
  $templateData[$row->date_year][$row->date_month][] = $row->name;
}
```

Then, in a template

```
<?php foreach ( $templateData as $year => $months ) : ?>
  <?php foreach ( $months as $month => $names ) : ?>
    <h2><?php echo $month, ' ', $year; ?></h2>
    <ul>
      <?php foreach ( $names as $name ) : ?>
        <li><?php echo $name; ?></li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

We do tonnage of this month grouping.  I use this expression to truncate arbitrary timestamps to timestamps that represent the first of the month.

```
   TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(action_time,'%Y-%m-01'))
```

This does the same thing as the Oracle-ism  `TRUNC(action_time,'MM')`

For example you could do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) NUM, TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(t.action_time,'%Y-%m-01')) MONTH
FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(t.action_time,'%Y-%m-01'))
```

This has the conceptual advantage that it maintains the timestampiness of the month-truncated data, so if you need to you can still compute time differences and do other timey and datey things if you need to.

As ravern pointed out, there's a small performance penalty (but it isn't bad!).  Some of our table columns are loaded using this function so they're already month-truncated.